# Performance testing for JAVA Backend and Cassandra for IOT Project

Tags: java, performance-testing, cassandra-2.0, iot, manual-testing

I am working on an IOT project for which I need to do performance testing.
Here are the details,

- Performance testing on **JAVA Backend application.**
- Performance testing on **CASSANDRA DATABASE**.

Data is pushed from JAVA Backend application to CASSANDRA DATABASE.

Please suggest me the best performance testing tool.

Answer (score -1):

A product to test the performance of a Cassandra Database is cstar_perf.

The Java backend can be tested in numerous ways, and it depends on whether you are interested in an open source or a paid product, and on the criticality of your application.